# Ignore cells that contain a certain word using textjoin/match formula

Tags: excel-formula, match, textjoin

The below formula compares two tables to match names and then returns those names it cannot find in the second table. What i would like it to do is exclude any names that contain the word `Agency`, note that the `STB` is varible and can change. So for example in the picture, it would just return `Joe Bloggs`.

```
Table 1                           Table 2

E-Name of employee                Name
Joe Bloggs                        Karin Matthews   
Joe Bloggs                        Tony Williams
Jane Doe                          Bill Johnson
Jane Doe
Agency STB Agency STB
Agency STB Agency STB
Agency STB Agency STB
Karin Mathews
Tony Williams
Bill Johnson


=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(HrsRoleEchoPay[E-Name of employee],AwardsFromEchoTbl[Name],FALSE)),HrsRoleEchoPay[E-Name of employee],""))
```

[image]

Comment: It's important you share your data, not only the result you want improved. Please don't post data as picture, because we want to help, but that requires your help too.

Comment: Edited, hopefully clearer

Comment: Would it not also return Jane Doe?

Comment: Yes it would but looks like i cropped Jane out when i  snap shot the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Office 365 you can do:

```
=LET( EN, HrsRoleEchoPay[E-Name of employee],
       N, AwardsFromEchoTbl[Name],
       F, FILTER( EN, NOT(ISNUMBER( FIND( "Agency", EN ) )) ),
       TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(F,N,FALSE)),F,"")) )
```

Comment: Thx, works fine on my computer, just need to test on others

Answer (score 1):

For older Excel the formula would be a bit longer:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",1,
          INDEX(HrsRoleEchoPay[E-Name of employee],
             AGGREGATE(15,6,
                (ROW(HrsRoleEchoPay[E-Name of employee])-ROW(HrsRoleEchoPay[[#Headers],[E-Name of employee]])) 
                /(NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Agency",HrsRoleEchoPay[E-Name of employee])))) 
                /(COUNTIF(AwardsFromEchoTbl[Name],HrsRoleEchoPay[E-Name of employee])=0), 
             ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A, 
                          SUM((NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Agency",HrsRoleEchoPay[E-Name of employee]))))
                          *(COUNTIF(AwardsFromEchoTbl[Name],HrsRoleEchoPay[E-Name of employee])=0)))))))
```